# How does GDB restore instruction after breakpoint

Tags: gdb

I have read that GDB puts a int 3 (opcode CC) at the wanted adress in the target program memory.

Si this operation is erasing a piece of instruction (1 byte) in the program memory.
My question is: How and When GDB replaces the original opcode when the program continues ?

When i type disassemble  in GDB, i do not see CC opcode. Is this because GDB knows it is him that puts the CC ?
Is there a way to do a raw disassemble, in order to see exactly what opcodes are loaded in memory at this instant ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How and When GDB replaces the original opcode when the program continues ?

I use this as an interview question ;-)

On Linux, to continue past the breakpoint, `0xCC` is replaced with the original instruction, and `ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, ...)` is done. When the thread stops on the next instruction, original code is again replaced by the `0xCC` opcode (to restore the breakpoint), and the thread continued on its merry way.

On x86 platforms that do not have `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP`, [trap flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag) is set in `EFLAGS` via `ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, ...)` and the thread is continued. The trap flag causes the thread to immediately stop again (on the next instruction, just like `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` would).

> When i type disassemble in GDB, i do not see CC opcode. Is this because GDB knows it is him that puts the CC ?

Correct. A program could examine and print its own instruction stream, and you can observe breakpoint `0xCC` opcodes that way.

> Is there a way to do a raw disassemble, in order to see exactly what opcodes are loaded in memory at this instant ?

I don't believe there is. You can use `(gdb) set debug infrun` to observe what GDB is doing to the inferior (being debugged) process.

> What i do not understand in fact is the exact role of SIGTRAP. Who is sending/receiving this signal ? The debugger or the target program?

Neither: after `PTRACE_ATTACH`, the *kernel* stops the inferior, then notifies the debugger that it has done so, by making debugger's `wait` return.

> I see a wait(NULL) after the ptrace attach. What is the meaning of this wait?

See the explanation above.

> Thread specific breakpoints?

For a thread-specific breakpoint, the debugger inserts a process-wide breakpoint (via `0xCC` opcode), then simply immediately resumes any thread which hits the breakpoint, unless the thread is the specific one that you wanted to stop.

Comment: Thanks, but i do not understand who replace this flag. In order to understand this mechanism i would like to write a small program in C that pthread_atach, put a breakpoint and do the something than GDB but i do not know how to do...

Comment: "I do not understand how to set TF flag" -- take a look at `man ptrace`, `PTRACE_SETREGS`. Also I missed `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP`, which is what is actually used on Linux and is much simpler. Updated the answer.

Comment: Can you give me a piece of C code that do the same thing than gdb ? Suppose i've already attach the process. Thanks

Comment: @Bob5421 Code that shows how to resume from a breakpoint is [here](https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/blob/master/2011/debuggers_part2_code/debuglib.c#L117). It's from Eli Bendersky. The accompanying article from his blog is [How debuggers work: Part 2 - Breakpoints](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/27/how-debuggers-work-part-2-breakpoints)

Comment: Thanks i have ready this article yesterday. What i do not understand in fact is the exact role of SIGTRAP. Who is sending/receiving this signal ? The debugger or the target program ?

Comment: I have also another question/remark. In some sample programs, i see a wait(NULL) after the ptrace attach. What is the meaning of this wait ?

Comment: And one more thing: how works Thread specific breakpoints ? If i replace in instruction by 0xcc, it is for all threads...

Comment: That is great thanks. Do you know how it works on OS X ? I would like to say it is the same thing. ptrace sys call is existing on OS X but something is missing