# How does gdb manage thread-specific breakpoints

Tags: gdb

When gdb puts a breakpoint in a Target process, it replaces one instruction by int3. I am wondering how it works when this breakpoint should ne active for a specific thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37862221/50617):

For a thread-specific breakpoint, the debugger inserts a process-wide breakpoint, then simply immediately resumes any thread which hits the breakpoint, unless the thread is the specific one that you wanted to stop.